# Adonis npm ci --production hangs

Tags: adonis.js, npm-ci

I have problem when deploying an Adonis project, After building, adonis suggest to do `npm ci --production` inside build folder. And after I do `npm ci --production`, the process is hangs

```
extractTree: sill extract faker@5.5.3 extracted to /root/dev/monas/build/node_modules/faker (2091ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete node_modules folder and npm install again